# Vim function to update class definition to reflect current location

Tags: automation, vim

I'm trying to take my vimscript to the next level. As a follow up to my other question about [generating a class definition from a file path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24164495/1946), how would you implement the following in vimscript?

Given I have a file at `lib/foo/bar/buz.rb` that looks like this:

```
module Foo
module Bar

   class Buz
     ...
   end

end
end
```

If I move the file to `lib/cat/dog/cow/buz.rb`, can I create a function to quickly update the file to look like this?

```
module Cat
module Dog
module Cow

  class Buz
    ...
  end

end
end
end
```

Comment: @romainl There are basic pieces here that I don't know how to perform in vim script. The pseudo code for this isn't hard, but I don't know where to begin when it comes to reading/writing buffers from vimscript. I don't know the idiomatic ways to do some of this basic stuff. I'm not sure what a satisfactory answer to your question about 'what did you try?' would look like.

Comment: A few lines of vimscript would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expand('%:p:h:t')` to get the current file's directory. Add additional `:h` modifiers to get parent directories. See `:help filename-modifiers`.

`substitute('foo', '^.', '\u&', '')` will upper-case the first letter.

To do the replacement in the buffer, a `:substitute`, probably with a `:help sub-replace-expression` will do.

Comment: Thanks this helped me get started. I solved my other question. Now onto this one.